# How to stop translate method from adding velocity?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a proof of concept project to graph data points on a table and I need to move the 0,0 position of the canvas from the top left to the bottom left, this is because when 1 is inputted the graph charts it at 9 instead of 1 because the computer thinks the origin is from the top left. Anyways, I'm trying to change the origin to the bottom left and it does indeed move the origin, but it also adds velocity to my little dot and I don't want that. If you need to see any more code then please ask, I'll show my draw function here:

```
this.draw = function(){
        c.beginPath();
        c.translate(0, 50);
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        c.fillStyle="white";
        c.fill();
        c.stroke();
    };
```

Comment: show some more code. with some more explanation. Are you talking about when your origin shifts from top left to bottom left it shows some animation ?

Comment: @pawankumar The origin does shift how I want it to, but the circle then starts moving downwards. And what code would you need to see, html, info on the variables?

Comment: anything which helps me see the working visually in any js fiddle

Comment: A [MCVE] would be very helpful here.